# What is the following Bach edition number?

Tags: identify-this-song, baroque, johann-sebastian-bach

I heard the following Bach Bouree but I'm unsure about what the edition number is. I looked for a long while until I found it recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming you want the BWV number)

This is tricky:  It is a transcription for guitar of the partita for violin solo #1, BWV 1002, *Tempo di borea*.

See e.g. [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0p-1Wk6Ojs)

Comment: I have discovered that it is Number 7 of the partitas.

Comment: @NeilMeyer: Pure ordinal numbers are of limited use, since different trackings are possible; e. g. whether the double is separately tracked or not, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partita_for_Violin_No._1_(Bach)).